# Why does my bower_install give me an error saying my package is not found?

Tags: bower, bower-install

I have the following bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "user_staging",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.0",
    "angular-loading-bar": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

When I issue: bower install user_staging then it appears to install everything but finishes by telling me this:

```
C:\G\user-staging\WebUserApp>bower install user_staging
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.15
bower validate      1.3.15 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>
 1.0.8
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.0-rc.1
bower validate      1.4.0-rc.1 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.g
t#^1.4.0
bower not-cached    git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#^0.2.0
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#^0.2.0
bower download      https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/archive/0.2.14.tar.
z
bower progress      angular-ui-router#^0.2.0 received 0.7MB of 1.7MB downloaded
 43%
bower progress      angular-ui-router#^0.2.0 received 0.8MB of 1.7MB downloaded
 49%
bower progress      angular-ui-router#^0.2.0 received 0.9MB of 1.7MB downloaded
 51%
bower progress      angular-ui-router#^0.2.0 received 0.9MB of 1.7MB downloaded
 56%
bower progress      angular-ui-router#^0.2.0 received 1.0MB of 1.7MB downloaded
 60%
bower progress      angular-ui-router#^0.2.0 received 1.1MB of 1.7MB downloaded
 67%
bower progress      angular-ui-router#^0.2.0 received 1.2MB of 1.7MB downloaded
 75%
bower ENOTFOUND     Package user_staging not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for the user_staging package on the internet.
If user_staging is your project and you're running bower install in the same folder as the bower.json file then you can just run "bower install" without any arguments to install your project's dependencies.